# onCreate() is undefined for the type of object and syntax error on token class invalid type

Tags: android

I'm new to android. I received the error as `method(onCreate) is undefined` for the type of object and syntax error on token class invalid type.

```
package com.ling;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Disp extends Activity{


    public class onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
public class onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display);
}
```

to

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display);
}
```

because `onCreate` is method not a class currently you are trying to return an class type from `onCreate` method

Comment: Thank you very much... successfull